# How to replace the a number with another using regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file named files, which contain

```
100-1-0_Message1_Tableau_problem.txt
1001-1-0_EDM_Queries_v2.mdb
1001-1-0_geocodes.xlsx
1001-1-0_losstypes.xlsx
1001-10-0_Exposure_Analysis_Tables_Needed.xlsx
```

I want to replace this file by incrementing the first part of the file name. i.e 001-1-0_EDM_Queries_v2.mdb to 1002-1-0_EDM_Queries_v2.mdb. Below regular expression with perl fails to do this.

```
perl -e '@lines = <>;foreach $f (@lines){$n = $f; $n=~s/^(\d+)/$1+1/g; print $n}' files
```

It prints

```
100+1-1-0_Message1_Tableau_problem.txt
1001+1-1-0_EDM_Queries_v2.mdb
1001+1-1-0_geocodes.xlsx
```

How do I tell the regular expression to add +1 instead of appending?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The replacement is normally just a string, it is not evaluated as an expression. To evaluate it, add the `e` modifier:

```
 $n =~ s/^(\d+)/$1+1/eg;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need change the substitution so that the replacement is an *expression* instead of a simple interpolated string. Do this by adding the `e` modifier, making it `s/^(\d+)/$1+1/eg`